# What does "return -1" mean in programming(javascript)

Tags: javascript, linked-list, return, return-value

I am learning linked list using js and found this in one of the methods. This returns a negative value. What does this mean. Here is the code:

```
// removes a given element from the
// list
removeElement(element)
{
    var current = this.head;
    var prev = null;

    // iterate over the list
    while (current != null) {
        // comparing element with current
        // element if found then remove the
        // and return true
        if (current.element === element) {
            if (prev == null) {
                this.head = current.next;
            } else {
                prev.next = current.next;
            }
            this.size--;
            return current.element;
        }
        prev = current;
        current = current.next;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Linked list in javascript

Comment: It's often used to indicate an error or "no value".

Comment: This makes little sense in this case. When the value (`element`) is found and removed, this function returns the exact same value it was given by the caller, and in the other case it returns -1. It might then better return a boolean: true when the value was found and removed, and false otherwise.

Comment: **-1** used to be returned on functions with numeric return values as **false**. Many languages are more consistent on types than Javascript with predefined input and output types. You can see the same behaviour in [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf?retiredLocale=de). In your case that does not make much sense.

Answer (score 1):

from the code you showed u can see that:

```
return -1;
```

will be ran only when:

```
while (current != null) => false
```

meaning the program will return -1 when current is null this is done because without this data validation an error would be thrown when running

```
current.element
```

as its not possible to get the (.element) of a null value.

TLDR:
programmers return -1 when the other option is undesirable (in this case an error)